# Find the table with the GUID as a name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have tables with the `GUID` as their names which is gets generated.

For example:

I have the tables with names of:

```
FD962987-AA3E-441C-B608-2392B68A5287

508482AF-EFCF-41C1-B083-D51BF37C3590
```

And also having some other tables in the database.

I just want to find the table with the name as `GUID`.

My try:

```
SELECT name 
FROM sys.tables 
WHERE LEN(tables.name) = 36
```

The above query works fine but when I have other tables(which are not GUID names) with the same len of table name getting displayed.

Comment: Or in addition to your current check check that `charindex('-') = 9`

Comment: @DaleBurrell, The position of `-` is fixed?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT 
    name 
FROM 
    sys.tables 
WHERE 
    LEN(tables.name) = 36 
    AND (tables.name LIKE '%-%-%-%-%') --OR tables.name LIKE '%-____-____-____-%')
```

Answer (score 2):

If your MS SQL Server version supports it (2012+) you could use [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) for this.
A TRY_CONVERT returns NULL when the conversion fails.

```
SELECT t.name 
FROM sys.tables t 
WHERE LEN(t.name) = 36 
  AND TRY_CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, t.name) IS NOT NULL;
```

Or you could use a LIKE with character ranges.   But it's a rather anti-golfcode method.
Since a [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql?) has a very specific format that only uses the characters `ABCDEF0123456789` between 4 dashes.

```
SELECT t.name 
FROM sys.tables t 
WHERE t.name like '[A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9]-[A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9]-[A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9]-[A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9]-[A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9]'
```